# I would like to find the mail attached to a script

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

Can anyone help me find out who is the owner of a script ?
We added a script on my website 2 years ago and I can't find out to which mail address it is attached : https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbz-weX3Qj1c3IbHaVmEI7YhTE0wfE4YSvCav3y5IifmN7xJAQrE/exec

Comment: The script is not public.  How is the script attached to an email?

Comment: The OAuth consent screen might show the script owner email... but you will only get the OAuth consent screen if the script requires authorization to run. If you are using Google Workspace accounts you might other other ways to find the script owner.